# Idiomatic expression alternative 'to end of the queue'?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Let's say I am at a pub with a few of my friends, and we are sitting at the bar.

We are all sitting on adjacent seats. So, two of us would be sitting on at the either ends of the (queue?).

NP3, NP4, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, NP1, NP2

Here P1 and P5 are at the ends.

I have used the word "queue" as a placeholder, what alternative word can I use instead of queue?

Comment: What do  NP and P stand for? N? Person?.

Comment: Your friends are sitting (*in a row*) at the bar. A is at one end while H is at the opposite end.

Comment: It's only a queue if you are waiting to be served one at a time. If you are just sitting drinking, it's a row.

Comment: @Mari-LouA NP means NonPerson, P means Person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say "either ends of the *line*/*row*".